# zero-divisors of a ring constitute an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I want to know if
"zero-divisors of a ring constitute an ideal iff each pair of zero-divisors of the ring has a nonzero annihilator?"

the crucial point for zero-divisors of a ring to constitute an ideal is to check if the sum of each pair of zero-divisors is again a zero-divisor. so one direction is trivial:
if each pair of zero-divisors of the ring has a nonzero annihilator then 
zero-divisors constitute an ideal.

what about the converse?

thanks.

---

**Update**

by ''each pair of zero-divisors has a nonzero annihilator'' i mean "for any pair of distinct zero-divisors like $a$ and $b$ we have a nonzero element $c\in R$ s.t. $ca=cb=0$.

Comment: What do you mean with ''each pair of zero-divisors has a nonzero annihilator''?

Comment: @13571 Is it a commutative ring? Otherwise, right or left annihilator? Also as commented above, your writing is not clear, 'pair' in what sense?

Comment: @AnyAD when the commutative algebra tag is used, we usually assume the ring in question is commutative.

Comment: by ''each pair of zero-divisors has a nonzero annihilator'' i mean "any distinct zero-divisors $a$ and $b$ has a nonzero common annihilator"

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for that.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ do the zero divisors form a group ?

Comment: thank you reuns